# Ruby/Rails is contradicting itself, what should I do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to learn Ruby on Rails, I have installed Ruby, `ruby -v` gives `ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x86_64-darwin18]` and I have installed rails using `gem install rails` however when I run `rails -v` I get the following dialogue.

```
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.
```

I then do as the prompt asks and run `sudo gem install rails` (inputting my pw) which gives me;

```
Successfully installed rails-6.0.2.2
Parsing documentation for rails-6.0.2.2
Done installing documentation for rails after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

to check that Rails has installed properly I run `rails -v` again, and again I get;

```
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.
```

Am I missing something very obvious?

Comment: It seems you've messed something with your rvm/rbenv installation. Maybe you should reinstall it? If I remember correctly, you're using `rbenv`, is that rails? What does `gem install rails` (without `sudo`, which you should not use for gem installation with rbenv or rvm) return?

Comment: It seems like the your PATH is not set correctly. See what `which rails` and `which gem` does. Are you using `rbenv` or `rvm`? If so make sure it's configured correctly.

Comment: Yeah, I am using `rbenv`. If I run `gem install rails` I get an ERROR due to denied permission

Comment: Like eikes wrote, what does `which ruby` return? What does `rvm list` return?

Comment: @eikes I think it is definitely something to do with my PATH, it has been bugging me all day. (I am using `rbenv`)

Comment: `which rails` give `/usr/bin/rails`

Comment: and `which ruby` gives `/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby`

Comment: `which gem` gives `/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/gem`

Comment: have you tried `sudo rails -v`? or installing rails without sudo?

Comment: Do not install gems with `sudo`. Its really insecure as the gem or any of its dependencies can execute code during the installation as the super user. Secondly you're just setting yourself up for permission issues. Throwing sudo at any problem that pops up is a really bad idea.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use sudo to install gems when you use rbenv. One of the main benefits to using rbenv or RVM is that you don't need to install gems system wide. It's likely that you've broken your rbenv installation slightly by writing gem folders as root. Try uninstalling ruby system wide, then uninstalling and reinstalling rbenv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to manage your Ruby/Rails environment is to use a tool like `rvm` and never use the system Ruby/Rails. Changing Ruby/Rails versions globally for all your apps will most likely break them, so you want each app to be locked to a specific Ruby/Rails version and only upgrade each one manually.

1. Start by installing RVM locally for your user:

```sh
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
echo "source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bash_profile
source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

2. Make a directory for your app.

```sh
mkdir my_rails_app && cd my_rails_app
```

3. Make a local `.ruby-version` and `.ruby-gemset` for each project:

```sh
echo 2.6.5 > .ruby-version
echo my_rails_app > .ruby-gemset
rvm reload
```

4. Then install rails only for the specific gemset "my_rails_app" (I usually give each app its own gemset).

```sh
gem install rails
rails new my_rails_app .
```

Comment: NOTE: You could also do this by switching ruby versions and gemsets with `rvm use 2.6.5 && rvm gemset use my_rails_app`, but it's best you create the `.ruby-version` and `.ruby-gemset` files so that rvm automatically detects the version when you cd to that directory